# Por qué se sobrecarga el AsyncTask cuando se hacer Conexión a Web Service

Tags: android-asynctask

Estoy haciendo una App para que guarde datos desde el Dispositivo, por ayuda de un Web Service, este automáticamente los tiene que guardar en una base de Datos SQL Server.

Utilizo los métodos Asíncronos para hacer consulta de Logeo y cambio de interfaz, y devuelve los datos necesarios.

El problema está al momento de querer almacenar los datos con dirección del Web Service. Pues este cuelga directamente la App.

**Nota**: Revicé el Web Service y guarda correctamente en la Base de Datos correspondiente.

```
 @Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_info_general);

    lblNombreEjecutivo = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.lblNombreEjecutivo);
    lblNoReporte = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.lblNoReporte);
    btnReporte= (Button) findViewById(R.id.btnReporte);
    txtUnidadVentas = (EditText) findViewById(R.id. txtUnidadVentas);
    txtNombreTienda = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.txtNombreTienda);
    txtNombreCliente = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.txtNombreCliente);
    txtTelefonoContacto = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.txtTelefonoContacto);
    txtEmail =(EditText) findViewById(R.id.txtEmail);
    txtCodigoProcudto = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.txtCodigoProcudto);
    txtNoLote = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.txtNoLote);
    txtCantidadReclamada=(EditText) findViewById(R.id.txtCantidadReclamada);
    txtmedidaReclamo = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.txtMedidaReclamo);
    txtProblemaPresentado = ( EditText) findViewById(R.id.txtProblemaPresentado);
    txtMuestras = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.txtMuestas);
    txtVisita = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.txtVisita);
    txtDirecc_visita = (EditText)findViewById(R.id.txtDirecc_visita);
    txtExistencia = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.txtExistencia);
    txtAdicional = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.txtAdicional);


    Bundle bundle = getIntent().getExtras();
    lblNombreEjecutivo.setText( bundle.getString("User"));
    lblNoReporte.setText((bundle.getString("Reporte")));

    btnReporte.setOnClickListener( new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View view) {
            pDialog = new ProgressDialog(InfoGeneral.this);
            pDialog.setProgressStyle(ProgressDialog.STYLE_SPINNER);
            pDialog.setMessage("Agregando...");
            pDialog.setCancelable(true);
            pDialog.setMax(100);
            pDialog.show();

            WSEncabezado tarea = new WSEncabezado();
            tarea.execute("");

            WSOrdenMax maxi = new WSOrdenMax();
            maxi.execute();

        }
    });
```

Luego con ayuda de este Asíncrona, llamaría al servicio para ser de puente para guardar datos en el SQL Server

```
 private class WSEncabezado extends AsyncTask<String, Integer, Boolean> {
    String resultado="0";
    @SuppressWarnings("WrongThread")
    @Override
    protected Boolean doInBackground(String... params) {
        boolean result = true;

        final String SOAP_ACTION = "http://Ejemplo.com/Reporte";
        final String METHOD_NAME = "Reporte";
        final String NAMESPACE = "http://ejemplo.com/";
        final String URL = "http://192.166.182.4:80/WS_CONTROL/Service1.asmx";

        SoapObject request = new SoapObject(NAMESPACE, METHOD_NAME);
        request.addProperty("canal", txtUnidadVentas.getText().toString());
        request.addProperty("usuario", lblNombreEjecutivo.getText().toString());
        request.addProperty("NombreTienda", txtNombreTienda.getText().toString());
        request.addProperty("nombre_cliente", txtNombreCliente.getText().toString());
        request.addProperty("telefono_cliente", txtTelefonoContacto.getText().toString());
        request.addProperty("Email", txtEmail.getText().toString());
        request.addProperty("Cod_Producto", txtCodigoProcudto.getText().toString());
        request.addProperty("Lote", txtNoLote.getText().toString());
        request.addProperty("Cant_Reclamada", txtCantidadReclamada.getText().toString());
        request.addProperty("Medida", txtmedidaReclamo.getText().toString());
        request.addProperty("Razon", txtProblemaPresentado.getText().toString());
        request.addProperty("Muestras", txtMuestras.getText().toString());
        request.addProperty("Visita_Requerida", txtVisita.getText().toString());
        request.addProperty("Direcc_Visita", txtDirecc_visita.getText().toString());
        request.addProperty("Inventario", txtExistencia.getText().toString());
        request.addProperty("Observaciones", txtAdicional.getText().toString());

        SoapSerializationEnvelope envelope = new SoapSerializationEnvelope(SoapEnvelope.VER11);
        envelope.dotNet = true;
        envelope.setOutputSoapObject(request);
        HttpTransportSE transporte = new HttpTransportSE(URL);

        try
        {

            transporte.call(SOAP_ACTION, envelope);

            SoapPrimitive resultado_xml =(SoapPrimitive)envelope.getResponse();
            String res = resultado_xml.toString();

            resultado = res;

        }
        catch (Exception e)
        {
            result = false;
        }

        return result;
    }


}
```

Pero al querer compilar, en el módulo que corresponde, es allí cuando manda este problema en el LogCat:

1. Elemento de lista

FATAL EXCEPTION: main

Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException

Espero su orientación y comentario favorable.

Comment: Hola Giezi, bienvenido al sitio!, te invito a realizar el [tour] para 

conocer el funcionamiento básico del sitio y obtener tu primera 

[medalla](https://es.stackoverflow.com/help/badges)! para que 

obtengas buenas respuestas, para esto te sugiero leer [ask], saludo

Answer (score 2):

El problema principal por el cual marca error esta definido en el LogCat y es :

> Caused by: java.lang.SecurityException: ConnectivityService: Neither
>   user 10048 nor current process has
>   android.permission.ACCESS_NETWORK_STATE

Debes declarar el permiso en tu `AndroidManifest.xml` ,

```
 <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" />
 <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_NETWORK_STATE" />
```

Comment: Muchas gracias Jorge, lo he cambiado. Error mío, me faltaba agregar el persmiso de Acces_NetWork_State. Eso era solo el preliminar del problema.

Comment: FATAL EXCEPTION: main

Comment: Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException